# Angular flex-layout based structure issue

Tags: angular, sass, angular-flex-layout

I currently have this kind of setup on [Stackblitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kmub.png)

I would like to amend it so that it is re-structured as follows;

[image]

I'm struggling to place Test2 div underneath Test1 div.

Comment: Easiest way is to think of it as a row with 2 columns where first column has 2 rows. ex: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rddbsf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping test1 and test2 in a div with `fxLayout.sm="column"` while the parent div (containg all three) will have `fxLayout.sm="row"`

it will look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wan0g7yz/)